# The meaning of "the resources of a police force"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [The Economist: Hong Kong remains crucially important to mainland China](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2019/08/08/hong-kong-remains-crucially-important-to-mainland-china): (paragraph 2, setence 2)

> But the fluid tactics of the black-clad vanguard, which is increasingly using violence, has challenged **the resources of a police force** determined to crack down on the protests.

What does "the resources of a police force" mean here?
Does it mean "the people in that police force"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "resource" is any supply of money, materials or people that the police force can use to achieve their aims. The police force aims to "crack down on protestors" but it is finding that it doesn't have as many officers, or as much equipment and money as it wants.

Comment: Crisp answer! I have another question, why the author writes "has challenged" but not "have challenged", since I see that the subject, "the fluid tactics" is plural.